# Does the underlying data HAVE to be changed between beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows()?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a few subclasses of QAbstractListModel that use external data as the underlying data source:

```
class My_Model: public QAbstractListModel 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit My_Model(QObject* parent = nullptr);
private:
    Data_Source* _data_source; // external data
}
```

Within the data source there is an array that the model accesses:

```
class Data_Source
{
public:
   bool append_data_to_array(int num);
private:
   std::vector<int> _data_array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

The models make changes to the data source within its setData() implementation like so:

```
_data_source->append_data_to_array(new_value);
```

Since all the models are presenting the same data, when _data_sources changes (items are appended for example), rows need to be added in all the models presenting this data. My question is, do I HAVE to call beginInsertRows() in all the connected models BEFORE _data_source changes and endInsertRows() AFTER _data_source has changed, or can I just change the data and call beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() back-to-back after _data_source has changed? Both ways seem to be working fine but the documentation states that:

> When reimplementing insertRows() in a subclass, you must call this
> function before inserting data into the model's underlying data store.

This suggests that that code that changes the data must, for some reason, be sandwiched in between calls to beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() like this:

```
beginInsertRows()
_data_source->append_data_to_array(new_value);
endInsertRows()
```

Is there some "under the hood" reason that the code must look like this or is it ok to call beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() afterwards like this:

```
_data_source->append_data_to_array(new_value);

beginInsertRows()
endInsertRows()
```

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows)

Comment: I read the docs on this. I see it mentions the  rowsAboutToBeInserted() signal for proxies. Is that the only reason to call beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() in the sandwiched way? The docs aren't clear if that is the only reason of if there are other reasons.

Comment: Agreed, it's not entirely clear. Was just pointing to the docs to see if they helped. I've always put relevant code between the `begin`/`end` calls; but not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: If you don't add data then your view will get confused and add an empty line. Or the QSortFilterProxyModel inbetween will get notified wrong and may also produce wrong results. Don't do it.